# Exceptions silently swallowed in play framework

Tags: java, exception, logging, playframework

I encountered a problem with logging exceptions using play framework.

Suppose, we have some runnable class RunnableClass, that can be initialized in Global class and can be executed in Executor service.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void beforeStart(Application app) {
        Runnable runnableClass = new RunnableClass();
        runnableClass.setSmth(new Smth());
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableClass, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Suppose, we need to operate with Smth class in run() method of RunnableClass.

```
private class RunnableClass implements Runnable {

    private Smth smth;

    public void setSmth(Smth smth) {
        this.smth = smth;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        smth.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But for some reason we will not get here NullPointerExcception or any else exception. Obviously, that stack trace of this exception will be logged at least to console, but i see nothing either in console, nor in application.log file.

My version of play - 2.2.1, sbt launcher version - 0.13.0, application.conf file - default.

I tried next link:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/SettingsLogger